# Is my monitor CCFL or LED Backlight?

Tags: display, led, backlight

I opened up my monitor. I am not familiar with how to detect CCFL vs LED backlight. Can someone assist and explain why it is either CCFL or LED?

Here is an image of the inside of my monitor:

[image: image of the inside of my monitor]

Comment: What's the manufacturer and the model number?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, it is a Rombica SkyView M23-MF

Answer (score 0):

CCFL and LED are two different types of backlights, essentialy two very different types of technologie and there is no advantage in mixing them e.g. because their power requirements  are different. Therefore it's either either CCFL or LED.

To find out which one you have you need to look at the the light source. CCFL look like one continous tube, LED usually have multiple small yellow point on a strip. Yours looks like an Edge-Type CCFL backlight, but it's hard to tell.

Here's an example of a CCFL (top) and a LED (bottom) light:

[image]

[image]

Yours looks like an Edge-Type CCFL backlight.

Note: Usually there are two types of backlights: Edge-Type (with one CCFL-tube or one LED strip) and Direct-Type (multiple CCFL-tubes or multiple LED strips)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Do I have to open the panel itself to see the tube used?

Comment: @Mokee yes, unless you can see it without opening the panel

Comment: (If this answers your question, please consider to hit the checkmark to accept this as an answer)